# DYNDNS - How many hosts are necessary for a mailserver and a ftp server and a webserver

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns

A local network is connected to internet thru my own router (NETGEAR with DD-WRT software running dnsmasq) which is connected to my ISP DSL box. My ISP provides me a dynamic IP address. I plan to use NO-IP for dyndns service I want to install a production server

```
As a web server for 2 or more apps (www.web_1.com, www.web_2.com) using apache and virtual host.
    I suppose that I can configure the names in DNS, resolves to my IP address, in the NO-IP configuration panel.

As a mail server.
    I suppose that I can configure the MX record, in the NO-IP configuration panel.

As an FTP server
    I suppose that I have configured some things in the NO-IP configuration panel.
```

I want to install a test server with the same functionality

How many hosts must I register?

2 (one for the production server and one for the test server).

or 6 (one fore each production or test services)

Any help is welcome

Comment: Depending on the load, this may all run well on a single machine.  It's conventional to use specific host names for each service, all pointing to the one machine (aliases in the DNS using `CNAME` RRs to point to the real name of the host).  This makes it easier if the load increases and you want to split these in the future, or you want to split for some other reason.  But none of that is set in stone, what you should do is what best suits your goals.

Comment: I am testing this configuration. My goal is not to buy a domain name and/or any services until everything run perfectly.Thank you for helping